How to create a factory function that preserves generic type information in Python?
I have the following function that returns a class with a generic type parameter:
T = TypeVar('T')

def create_property(event_bus: EventBus):
    class Property(Generic[T]):
        def __init__(self, validator: Callable[[T], bool]):
            self._validator = validator

        def __set_name__(self, obj: Any, name: str):
            self.name = name

        def __get__(self, obj: Any, type: Any) -> T:
            return obj.__dict__.get(self.name)

        def __set__(self, obj: Any, value: T):
            if not self._validator(value):
                raise ValueError("Invalid value")
            obj.__dict__[self.name] = value
            event_bus.publish()

    return Property

What I'm trying to do here is to create a class that has an EventBus bound to it so that I don't have to pass it as a constructor parameter.
My problem with the above code is that this will resolve to Property[Any] instead of Property[T] so the generic is lost somewhere along the way. How can I fix this function to preserve the generic?

Implementation notes:

Property class must be global to use it in return type annotation of create_property.
Inside create_property, subclass and bind event_bus.
Instantiate new Property class as separate variable prop, otherwise type hints are lost.
Instantiate descriptor object x, its type is determined by validator type.

from typing import Any, Callable

class EventBus:
    def publish(self):
        ...

class Property[T]:
    def __init__(self, validator: Callable[[T], bool]):
        self._validator = validator

    def __set_name__(self, obj: Any, name: str):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj: Any, type: Any) -> T:
        return obj.__dict__.get(self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj: Any, value: T):
        if not self._validator(value):
            raise ValueError("Invalid value")
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = value


def create_property[T](event_bus: EventBus) -> Callable[[Callable[[T], bool]], Property[T]]:
    class _Prop(Property[T]):
        def __set__(self, obj: Any, value: T):
            super().__set__(obj, value)
            event_bus.publish()

    return _Prop

prop = create_property(event_bus=EventBus())

def validator(value: int) -> bool:
    return True

# pyright: strict

x = prop(validator)

Verification
$ pyright
0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations


The whole point of having a function is not to have the event bus in Property but to have the T argument as T and not as int after I call create_property.

@AdamArold Then I don't understand your use case. Please give more details on how you are going to use Property. You will need to associate generic Property with specific type to get type checking.

Property implements the Descriptor protocol so I use it in fields. That's why I need the T to be preserved because each property will have a different type. I don't want to pass the EventBus everywhere that's why I have this construct. It is analogous to currying and partial application.

@AdamArold Take a look at the working example and adjust for your needs.

Your answer reproduces my problem

@AdamArold in my PyCharm it works as expected. What IDE do you use?

I use Cursor with Pylance, that's why it doesn't work for you probably.

It says TypeVar "T" is already in use by an outer scope, Method "__set__" overrides class "Property" in an incompatible manner and Expression of type "type[_Prop[Unknown, T@_Prop]]" is incompatible with return type "type[Property[T@create_property]]" so in fact there are multiple errors in this code.

@AdamArold assuming that Pylance is based on Pyright, probably the updated solution will work for you.

Thanks. This seems so convoluted. There must be a simple way to dynamically create a generic class that can use things from closures (event_bus here).

@AdamArold do you accept the answer?
